# Why does getExternalFilesDirs return different results depending on which context is used?

Tags: android, android-context

This one is very strange. I use `Context.getExternalFilesDirs` to get the path to the removable SD card. This works just fine on the LG X Power running Android 6.0.1. However, on the LG Spirit H440N on Android 6.0 it gives me different results depending on which context is used. If I call this method on

- the activity, I get an array of size 2 containing both internal and removable SD card file paths
- the Application context, I get an array of size 1 only containing the path to the internal file path

Why do I get a different result depending on which context I call the method on? Do permissions work differently in each context?

Note that I've listed both permissions in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: `Why does getExternalFilesDirs return different results depending on which context is used?` Strange question. You said it does not on LG X power.

Comment: `Note that I've listed both permissions in the manifest:` Irrelevant. You do not need those permissions to call that function.

Comment: Thanks for your extremely useful comments!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I also think so. I faced the same problem with Redmi devices.

`application` and `applicationContext Context.getExternalFilesDirs(null)` 
shows me only 1 file (Internal storage), but when I used `baseContext` and `FirebaseMessagingService context` it worked great.

So, I think `baseContext.getExternalFilesDirs(null)` will work for you.